# Finding the impulse response of a system with known input and output

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

I'm trying to find out the impulse response for my system, I have a given input and output matrices stored in ".npy" file, the goal is to calculate the impulse response using Fourier transformation.
this is the code of the process:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import scipy.signal as sg


working_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
t_path = os.path.join(working_directory, 't.npy')
x_t_path = os.path.join(working_directory, 'x_t.npy')
y_t_path = os.path.join(working_directory, 'y_t.npy')

t = np.load(t_path)
x_t = np.load(x_t_path)
y_t = np.load(y_t_path)
x_t[np.abs(x_t) < 1e-10] = 1e-10


# Compute the Fourier transforms of the input and output
X_f = np.fft.fft(x_t)
Y_f = np.fft.fft(y_t)

# Compute the frequency response
H_f = np.divide(Y_f, X_f, out=np.zeros_like(Y_f), where=X_f!=0)

# Regularize the frequency response to avoid division by zero
H_f[np.abs(H_f) < 1e-10] = 1e-10

# Compute the impulse response
h_t = np.fft.ifft(H_f)
```

and those are the input and output in time domain figures:
[input, output in time domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIPfe.png)
input and output in frequency domain "which is one of the terrible results i assume":
[input, output in frequency domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vlvoi.png):
the impulse response in time domain which is definitely wrong:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKbAp.png)
so how can i solve the problem, it's required to use Fourier transformation for the code
thanks for your time

I tried to use this code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os


working_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
t_path = os.path.join(working_directory, 't.npy')
x_t_path = os.path.join(working_directory, 'x_t.npy')
y_t_path = os.path.join(working_directory, 'y_t.npy')

t = np.load(t_path)
x_t = np.load(x_t_path)
y_t = np.load(y_t_path)

# Ensure the input and output signals are aligned and have the same size
assert len(x_t) == len(y_t), "Input and output signals must have the same size"

# Calculate the cross-correlation between the input and output signals
cross_corr = np.correlate(y_t, x_t, mode='full')

# Normalize the cross-correlation to obtain the impulse response
impulse_response = cross_corr / np.sum(x_t**2)

# Calculate the time vector for the impulse response
dt = t[1] - t[0]
t_impulse = np.arange(-len(x_t) + 1, len(x_t)) * dt
```

and it gave me this impulse response figure which is the right one i think[the desired response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqnLB.png)